# How to calculate this partial derivative?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, derivatives, partial-derivative

given the function:
$$
v_h = \left[ \sum_{i=1}^N r_{h,i} \cdot w_{h,i} - \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{i=1}^N r_{t,i} w_{t,i} \right]^2
$$
I would like to compute the following:
$$
\frac{\partial v_h}{\partial w_h} = \;?
$$
$$
\frac{\partial v_h}{\partial r_h}= \;?
$$
$$
\frac{\partial v_h}{\partial w_h \partial r_h}= \;?
$$
The problem for me is the double sum in the second term. Example of the function with $N=2$ and $T=2$ for $t=1$:
$$
v_1=\left[ \left( r_{1,1}\cdot w_{1,1} + r_{1,2} \cdot w_{1,2}\right) - \frac{1}{2} \left( r_{1,1}\cdot w_{1,1} + r_{1,2} \cdot w_{1,2} + r_{2,1}\cdot w_{2,1} + r_{2,2} \cdot w_{2,2} \right) \right]^2
$$

Comment: What about it is giving you trouble? The derivative is linear. Do you see how that's relevant here?

Comment: Questions: is $r_{t,i}\cdot w_{t,i}$ the same as $r_{t,i} w_{t,i}$? Do you mean $\frac{\partial^2v_t}{\partial w_{t,i}\partial r_{t,i}}$ ?

Comment: The second summation uses $t$ as a summation variable. Which is frankly not a good idea, seeing as $t$ is used outside the sum as well.

Comment: @blamocur yes it's the same

Comment: @Arthur what do you mean by "not a good idea"?

Comment: I think what @Arthur might mean is:  using $t$ for summation is not illegal, but if you implemented this in software you would modify $t$ during the summation and end up sending the result to a wrong $v_t$. And even without programming it is somewhat confusing.

Comment: @blamocur Not just software. Look at the term $r_{t,i} w_{t,i}$ inside the sum. I can't tell whether they both use the summation $t$, or if one or both are using the $v_t$ $t$. I can guess, sure. But I really, really shouldn't have to guess something like that.

Comment: @Arthur look at the example at the bottom. You don’t have to guess.

Comment: @Barbab It’s good that you give an example, but our point is that better notation wouldn’t need an example. Just trust us that it’s not recommendable. I’d recommend $t’$ or maybe $s$ or $u$ in the sum to suggest the (presumable?) connection to $t$.

Comment: What do you really need ? Shall we assume that $w_t$ is a vector of dimension N-by-1 ? so you are asking the derivative of the scalar $v_t$ wrt a vector? is this good for you ?

Comment: ok I edited the indexes

Comment: @Steph yes, $w_h$ is a vector of dimension N-by-1

Answer (score 1):

Let denote your function as
$ 
v_t = y_t^2 $
where
$$
y_t 
=
\mathbf{r}_t : \mathbf{w}_t
- \frac{1}{T} \mathbf{r}_t : \mathbf{w}_t + C
$$
The colon operator denotes the inner product between vectors
and $C$ is a constant that does not depend on $\mathbf{r}_t,\mathbf{w}_t $ .
It follows using chain rule that
$$
\frac{\partial v_t}{\partial \mathbf{w}_t}
=
2 y_t 
(1- \frac{1}{T}) \mathbf{r}_t
$$